# Nginx - Reverse Proxy a WebSocket server with multiple paths

Tags: nginx, websocket, reverse-proxy

I guess that the answer to my question will be very easy, but unfortunately I've not been able to figure out by myself!

I have Nginx running on Server A (192.168.1.1) acting as a reverse proxy for a WebSocket server on Server B (192.168.1.2). This last server is listening on port 1234 and has 2 paths, so we can connect to the following addresses:

```
ws://192.168.1.2:1234/path1
ws://192.168.1.2:1234/path2
```

I've been able to successfully connect to Path1 through the proxy (ws://192.168.1.1/websocket/path1) by adding the following configuration:

```
location /websocket/path1 {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2:1234/path1;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

Now I would like to make it general enough to match also the second path (instead of creating a similar rule for path2), I tried something like:

```
location /websocket {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2:1234;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

But in this way I can't reach the WebSocket.

Do you have any idea about what's wrong?

Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was really easy, it worked by putting a "slash" at the end of the urls:

```
location /websocket/ {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2:1234/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

I was quite sure to have already tried that way, but seems like I was wrong! :)